# Semaphore doesn't works with PhantomJs DesiredCapabilities

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, semaphore

When I run this code with commented `//driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);`, All works fine. I can see only two "PhantomJS" system process.

[2 process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuG5Y.jpg) But if I run this code with uncommented `driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);`, The amount "PhantomJS" system processes more than 2 : [more than 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFJ0M.jpg)  ... Why?

```
    PhantomJsDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    Semaphore s = new Semaphore(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s.acquire();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
                try {
                    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    System.out.println("Start: " + getName());
                    desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
                    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);
                    driver.get("https://community.oracle.com/");
                    driver.quit();
                    System.out.println("Stop: " + getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    driver.quit();
                } finally {
                    driver.quit();
                    s.release();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe because you create it 2 times? `PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();`

Comment: Thanks, it's clear